# What is the best practice in NGRX in order to avoid a state property to get updated with the same value

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

The title is quite enough but I will add some code

```
interface State {
    toto: string[]
}
```

action: `setToto(["value1", "value2"])`

reducer: returns `{...state, toto: ["value1", "value2"]}`

selector: selectToto() returns `state.toto`

My angular view has a selectToto() | async somewhere and gets triggered while doing another setToto(["value1", "value2"]) with the exact same value which I dont want to occur.

For now, I used Lodash.isEqual to check deep equality but I dont feel great about this approach

```
    case Action.SetToto:
        if (isEqual(state.toto, action.payload)) {
            return state;
        }

        return {
            ...state,
            toto: action.payload,
        };
```

Who should check for equality ?

- The selector ?
- The reducer ?
- My component ?

I hope you guys will come up with a best practice/design I am not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Def. not the component because that would be the hardest, and you possibly need to add that condition in multiple components, plus an action can be consumed by multiple reducers/effects.

So, either in the reducer, or the selector.
To do the latter, you need to create your custom factory, see this talk by Alex for an in-depth explanation with example.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7GKnjGCXzU

Comment: CustomMemoize -> createSelectorFactory seems the way to go, thanks !